# NLP on a xlsx worksheet - single column

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp, textblob

Hi I am seriously confused with how to conduct a NLP.
My goal is to conduct sentiment analysis on a 'Review' of a product.

```
data = pd.read_excel('ProductData.xlsx')
print(data.dtypes)

Clothing ID                 int64
Age                         int64
Review Text                object
```

the ['Review Text'] column is an **object**

```
from textblob import TextBlob
blob= TextBlob(data['Review Text'])
```

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

must be a **string**

```
data['Review Text'] = str(data['Review Text']) 
print(data['Review Text'].dtype)

= object
```

Could someone please help me tackle this problem.
How do I approach the task on performing a sentiment analysis on my data feature?

thankyou

Comment: Your `pandas` column is a whole SERIES of strings.  `TextBlob` wants exactly one string.  If you want it all processed at once, you'll need to join the words into a single paragraph.  In which case, `pandas` is not doing anything for you.

Comment: I don't want a single paragraph. I want to analyse the 'reviews' individually.  What is the best approach?

Comment: You'll have to do them in a loop, one at a time.

Comment: if ```pandas``` isn't working for me, what method do I use Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
blob = TextBlob(' '.join(df['Review Text'])
```

But this will combine all features as a single string. I don't know what type of processing you want to apply on each review. I think defining a function for processing and then using lambda to apply that function on each of your review is what you are looking for. May be something like this:

```
def process_text(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)


df['Review Text'].apply(lambda text: process_text(text))
```